# jQuery-Ajax retrieve function with PHP classes and functions

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi all I am new to using jQuery and I want to use the AJAX function for the search function my website. However I am having a bit of difficulty learning this as I can only find examples of using non function related PHP. I am currently trying to learn from this youtube example [jQuery Youtube Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yb3c-HljFro) . However this seems difficult to implement.

A little bit about what I am trying to achieve. I want to type in the postcode into my search bar and have it retrive all the relevant data fields that match using AJAX so that it is displayed in the div directly below the search bar.

As I'm not very familiar with jQuery I'm not sure if I am going about this the right way, any input will be warmly welcomed. Thank you in advance!

My code is as so

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<?php include("header.php"); 
$houseobject = new House();
$houseobject->search($_POST['term']);?>
<div id="mainContent">
  <div id="searchformWrap">
    <br/><h2>Search for Accomodation</h2>
    <div id="searchform"><br/><br/><br/>
      <form method="post" action="index.php" name="search" id="search_form">
        <div class="searchrow">
        <div class="searchlabel">Location</div>
        <div class="searchinput"> 
        <input type="text" name="term" id="term" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"/>
      </form>
      <div class="help">e.g. 'PO5' or 'Portsmouth'</div>
    </div> <!-- end input -->
  </div> <!-- end .row -->
  <div id="searchquery"> </div>
</div> <!-- End maincontent -->
```

classes/class.House.inc

```
<?php 
include ("connect.class.Database.inc");
class House extends Database {

  public function search ($term){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM houses 
      WHERE postcode like '%".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($term)."%'";
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
    $num_result = $result->num_rows;
    if($num_result > 0){
      while($rows =$result->fetch_assoc()) {        
        $this->data[]=$rows;
        //print_r($rows);
      }      
      return $this->data;
    } else{
       echo 'No Records Found';    
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
  }

}
```

js/ajax.js

```
  $('input#searchsubmit').on('click', function() {
    if ($.trim(term) != '') {
       $.post('classes/class.House.inc', {term: term}, function(data) {
          $('div#searchquery').text(data);
       });
    }
  });
}
```

I have usually been grabbing results by pointing the form on index.php to...

search.php

```
<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
  <th width="16" scope="row">id</th>
  <td width="95">bedrooms</td>
  <td width="140">description</td>
  <td width="104">roadname</td>
  <td width="71">postcode</td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 require("classes/class.House.inc");
 $obj = new House();
 if ($data = $obj->search($_POST['term']))
 {
    foreach($obj->data as $val){
      extract($val);
    }
 }
 ?>
 <tr>
      <td scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $bedrooms; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $roadname; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $postcode; ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post an example reponse from the `class.House.inc`? :-)

Comment: @BenCarey usually the form would go through search.php to echo out results I am going to add this now to the main question above.

Comment: Okay, well I am just writing up the script for you. Trying to make it as clear as possible for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the code carefully. It appears that there are several errors that need to be addressed.

1. The js is not contained within the jQuery ready function
2. The value of term is not being retrieved correctly
3. The on method is not being used properly
4. The ajax property 'url' must be lowercase
5. The data type must be html as the content is being written straight to the DOM
6. The writing method must be `html()` as the content is HTML
7. The page being pointed to was not a PHP page, and was not the correct search page

Below is the solution to all of these issues:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchsubmit').on("click", function(){
        // Get the value of the term field      
        var term = $('#term').val();
        // Proceed if the term is not empty
        if($.trim(term)!=''){           
            // Load the html result from the PHP script
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                data: 'term='+term,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    // Place the HTML response into the search query div
                    $('#searchquery').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution still does not seem to bring any data back from the database, do you think my function has any errors within it?

Comment: @gutigrewal First thing to test, go to the PHP page and make sure it is returning data correctly (either as JSON or HTML). Then you will know whether the script is working

Comment: @gutigrewal I will post up some more info, make not of the tips I have posted up, they are relevant to you :-)

Comment: thanks for that, very helpful advice! I'm now getting this error in the console `The event has been called, I am about to send a request to a PHP page ajax.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: term is not defined`

Comment: @gutigrewal You need to include the other code as well, the part that includes `var term = $('#term').val();`!

Comment: I included that I got this following error `POST http://localhost/undergradpad/classes/class.House.inc 412 (Precondition Failed) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
send jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
(anonymous function)` I have no idea what this means

Comment: Does this page exist and is it being executed as a PHP file? http://localhost/undergradpad/classes/class.House.inc

Comment: yes this file does exist you can see the code for this file above

Comment: What I mean, if you go to that address, does it work? Does it return any errors in the console?

Comment: oh no the code works perfectly if I execute it through search.php which can also be seen above. I get the results in a table. Just struggling to reach a jQuery Ajax based solution

Comment: @gutigrewal Okay, but just to confirm, does the full address of http://localhost/undergradpad/classes/class.House.inc resolve to the right file?

Comment: I tried your update but still no luck no data is being retrieved also there is no errors in the console when inspecting the elements.

Comment: @gutigrewal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19289/discussion-between-ben-carey-and-gutigrewal)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("input#searchsubmit").click(function(){
    if ($.trim(term) != '') {
        $("div#searchquery").load("demo_test.txt");
    }
  });
```

this should work fine..

Answer (score 0):

For searching with Ajax you don't want to submit the form, so `$houseobject->search($_POST['term']);?>` is wrong. For an Ajax call you have to handle a `click` or `keyup` event, which is better according to me, if we talk about Ajax.

You can create a new file, e.g. `ajax_search.php` and send the searched string (`trim`) to it. Then in your new file you can create a new `House` object and call its `search` method:

```
include('classes/class.House.inc');

if(isset($_POST['trim'])) {
    $house = new House();
    $json = $house->search();
    $html = '';
    // and build your HTML structure as you are doing it in search.php
    return $html;
}
```

The Ajax call:

```
$('input#searchsubmit').on('click', function() {
    var term = $('#term').val();

    if ($.trim(term) != '') {
        $.post('ajax_search.php', {term: term}, function(data) {
            $('div#searchquery').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have removed the downvote becuase you corrected error in your code, but I would still like to mention that some of the things you have mentioned in your answer are incorrect. Firstly, the form was not being submitted, it was a simply click and call event! So the first paragraph is pointless. You are also trying to write a JSON object into an HTML element!

Comment: For the first thing I couldn't understand why this is used: `$houseobject->search($_POST['term']);?>` at the top of `index.php`. Maybe I missed something? For the second think - yes, you are right. I didn't saw the edited question with `search.php` code and thought he will write the HTML in his `$.post`'s success part. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your jQuery code which will trap the keyup event and will fetch the typed value.

```
$('#searchBox').on('keyup', function() {
    var term = $('#term').val();
    if ($.trim(term) != '') {
        $.ajax({
            URL:'classes/class.House.inc', 
            data: 'term='+term,
            dataType :'json',
            success : function(text) {
                var strSrch = '';
                $.each(arr, function(k,v) {
                    var strSrch += '<td>'+v+'</td>'; //or whatever HTML you have
                });
                $('div#searchquery').text(strSrch);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now in the PHP file make an object of the class and call the search function.
if an ajax call has been made.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {//this will check if it is an ajax call.
if(isset($_REQUEST['term']) && trim($_REQUEST['term'] !='')){
  $objHouse = new House();
  $searchResult = $objHouse->search($_REQUEST['term']);
  die($searchResult); 
}
}
```

Now this will give you a json object.Which you can use in your ajax call success callback and decode it to make search result grid.

Comment: Firstly, `$(this).val();` is incorrect! You are not retrieving the value of the button! You are writing a JSON object to an HTML element. This will not work. Correct the code and I will remove the downvote :-)

Comment: I am sorry @BenCarey I took it to be textbox event.Now I have corrected it.

Comment: You have not corrected the value retrieval, and you are still returning a JSON object

Comment: I have edited your answer to remove your errors, it should be reviewed in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library that does that automatically, like http://phery-php-ajax.net you may manipulate the DOM while being able to make consecutive calls after everything is done. check the demos and you'll see

In your case, it would be like this (notice the new data-remote, it will make your form AJAXified automatically):

```html
 <form method="post" action="index.php" data-remote="search" name="search" id="search_form">
    <div class="searchrow">
    <div class="searchlabel">Location</div>
    <div class="searchinput"> 
    <input type="text" name="term" id="term" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"/>
  </form>
```

Inside your `House` class:

```php
class House extends Database {

   public function search ($term){
      $query = "SELECT * FROM houses 
      WHERE postcode like '%".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($term)."%'";
      $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
      $num_result = $result->num_rows;

      if ($num_result > 0){
        while($rows =$result->fetch_assoc()) {        
           $this->data[]=$rows;
        }      
        return $this->data;
      } 

      return false;
  }

  function ajax_search($data){ // $data got the 'term' key
    $r = new PheryResponse('#searchquery'); // select where to put the results
    $data = $this->search($data['term']);

    if ($data !== false){ // got results
      $table = new PheryResponse('<table/>', array(
        'width' => "500",
        'border' => "1",
        'cellpadding' => "5"
      ));

      $html = <<<HTML
<th width="16" scope="row">id</th>
  <td width="95">bedrooms</td>
  <td width="140">description</td>
  <td width="104">roadname</td>
  <td width="71">postcode</td>
</tr>
HTML;
      foreach ($data as $row)
      {
         $html .= <<<"HTML"
<tr>
  <td>{$row['id']}</td>
  <td>{$row['bedrooms']}</td>
  <td>{$row['description']}</td>
  <td>{$row['roadname']}</td>
  <td>{$row['postcode']}</td>
</tr>
HTML;
      }
      $table->html($html); // Set the html() of the table
      $r->html($table); // Add table to the #searchquery div
    }
    else
    {
      $r->text('No results found');
    }
    return $r; // return your answer
  }
}
```

Your controller will have this:

```php
$house = new House;

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'search' => array($house, 'ajax_search')
))->process();
```

That's it, the DIV will have the new data from your database.